# Am I qualified to review these posts?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

So, I've been through the Review queue a few times and I'm feeling slightly uncomfortable about whether I've done the right thing. Sure, I know how to check for a MCV question but sometimes there are questions about languages I've never even heard of!

They may seem OK to me but to someone who knows how to program in that language they may seem absurd.

I guess I have two questions here:

1. Is it OK to just have your best guess about whether a question 'Looks OK', or should you always skip when the subject matter is completely unfamiliar?
2. Should the Review queues perhaps show only questions with tags you're following? At least this way you're likely to be able to triage items you actually know something about!

---

RE gnat's suggestion of a duplicate question: Agree it's similar but I'm not really asking from a new users point of view, more that there are hundreds if not thousands of programming languages out there. Regardless of years of experience in language A we're being asked to comment on languages B, C and D...

Comment: Please specify which review queue you're focusing on.  Is this mostly about triage?  There are a few other review queues that have different goals, tools, and expectations for reviewers.

Comment: Filters are love, filters are life.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I really mean all of them, since in each case you're being asked to make a judgement call on something you may well not know about. For example new answers to old questions category is really asking the same thing as questions by new users - if you don't have expertise in that language you may well not be qualified to answer.

Comment: @Braiam no such tag filters on triage.  Close vote queue has them though.

Comment: @gnat Agree it's similar but I'm not really asking from a new users point of view, more that there are hundreds if not thousands of programming languages out there. Regardless of years of experience in language A we're being asked to comment on languages B, C and D....

Comment: we're not asked for that and that's the point. When you are sure about how to review, do it - and when in doubt, just skip

Comment: @Absinthe As you've been told, you *can't* talk about all of the queues.  There are so many queues and they're so radically different.  The question is *way* too broad if you want to talk about all of them.

Comment: @gnat Sure, that's my feeling too, just seems like a lot of time wasted, just throwing open the point that perhaps more targeted reviews would be beneficial

Comment: @Servy Not sure I follow, can you give some examples of which queues you're thinking of that my question would not cover?

Comment: @Absinthe I didn't say your question doesn't cover any queue.  I said that it's not answerable because you want it to cover every queue; for it to be answerable you need to change your question to only be about *one* queue.  They're each very different.  They have different requirements towards technical knowledge of the subject, and how they go about addressing that issue for reviewers.

Comment: @Servy That's my question - which queues arguably do not require technical knowledge? I'd suggest they all do in order to be able to provide effective triage.

Comment: @ryanyuyu which I believe is still and oversight of SE.

Comment: @Absinthe And explaining each of them is very different, because they all do very different things, and they all address technical expertise differently.  They are *eight completely different questions*.  And of course only one queue is about triaging, (that queue being Triage).

Answer (score 6):

> 1) Is it OK to just have your best guess about whether a question
>   'Looks OK', or should you always skip when the subject matter is
>   completely unfamiliar?

## If you're not confident, *skip it*.

Reviewing should be done in the utmost confidence that you're making good and sound decisions about what you're reviewing.  This requires you to take some time to discern what's going on.  Even if after you've taken that time and you're not 100% sure, skipping it is *fine*.

See also the PSA:  [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

> 2) Should the Review queues perhaps show only questions with tags
>   you're following? At least this way you're likely to be able to triage
>   items you actually know something about!

## Reviews are *not* about expertise in the subject.

You should be looking to see if the question (or answer) is suitable.  This depends on what queue you're in; look to the specific guidance of the queues themselves to be sure you're doing what you should be there.

Some questions may require more domain knowledge than you have.  If that's the case, skip it and move on to another question which could be reviewed.

Comment: "You should be looking to see if the question (or answer) is well-formed, free of spelling errors, on-topic, concise, and would in your reasonable judgment be answerable by someone who was an expert in it." That depends a lot on what queue your in.  If you're in the first posts queue, sure.  If you're in another queue, then no, that's not what you're doing.

Comment: @Servy:  There - made it agnostic.

Comment: "good and sound decisions about what you're reviewing" [citation needed] I was under the impression that in the suggested edits review queue we only accepted monkeys.

Comment: @Braiam Watch it... ;)