# Why was this answer by OP declared link-only answer and deleted?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, triage, link-only-answers

I'm concerned about one of my reviews from triage queue that got disputed yesterday:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22112679

The reason why I still think this is a useful answer which should not have been deleted are as follows:

- The answer comes from the OP, so it is probably **the one and only answer** to the OPs question.
- It contains the most important relevant information in text.
- Therefore it is complete even without the link.

It would have even been enough to say and accept as answer

> Increasing JVM Heap space solved it!

This is 36 chars and thus above the legit minimum of 30 chars. Anyone with Java experience knows how to increase JVM available memory using the `-Xmx` command line parameter - there are several ways depending on the actual Java application in question and how it is launched (operating system service, from command line, shell script, double-click on a .jar file, etc.). The link given IMHO is just additional information on **one method** to achieve this and is not required for this to be useful.

Calling for `link-only-answer` here in my eyes is not appropriate while I don't say this is a high quality answer. I would have understood downvotes by people asking for a more detailed explanation in comments area. On the other hand: how often do new users with 1rep come back after 4.5 months and answer their question? Most of them madly stay unanswered for ever (beside answers never getting accepted, but that's off topic).

**Disclaimer**:

I'm quite new to the review stuff. This dispute beside failed review audits triggered either an automatic or manually moderated(?) 4 day ban from all review queues - so yes I have made mistakes. I'm not bagging for unban, but outing here my possible mistake and possibly still wrong thinking in order to get additional opinions and learn doing better reviews in future. So far it seems to me this might have been an accidental deletion as none of the users that voted for deletion have any Java background (solely judged from Stack Overflow activity!) and it feels like I'm just in collateral 'damage'.

Comment: That review isn't an audit, it's an actual review, so if you were review banned for it, it was a manual moderator action.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: "So far it seemes to me this might have been an accidental deletion as none of the users that voted for deletion have any Java background" Judging whether or not something is an answer does not require domain expertise.  Judging whether or not an answer is a *good* answer often does, but not if it *is* an answer.

Comment: It was just undeleted and edited by a moderator, as well as it now has an upvote. At the very least this should prevent it from being an audit. Too bad so many reviewers in the LQPRQ can't seem to differentiate between an answer and everything that isn't an answer reliably.

Comment: I agree with you that this answer should not have been deleted. So I looked into your review ban. It was manually imposed by a moderator, and they listed some of your other incorrect reviews. None of them seem like obviously incorrect decisions to me. I personally wouldn't have imposed a ban based on these reviews. In the meantime, the best thing for you to do is to go through the review queue advice on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650, and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552.

Comment: @Servy that's right, I'm also judging posts out of my domain expertise from review queues. Possibly I should have more frequently made use of the **skip** button. I considered a moderated ban most likely because there was a delay of at least 12 hours from disputes to ban.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The revision of the answer displayed in the review definitely seemed like spam, especially with a sketchy domain name (*should we expect reviewers to verify links in reviews?*). It also seems like an opinion about the user's findings of the link's content instead of a proper answer, and could be better placed as a comment. Don't assume that the reader knows what steps to take or commands to use - [Reviews are not about expertise in the subject](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372727). I somewhat agree with the reviewers that it should be deleted as it doesn't explain how this would resolve the issue, especially as it wasn't answering a programming/coding question:

> Seems that increasing the memory available to the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) was the answer. http://www.messiahpsychoanalyst.org/wikihow/index.php/How_to_Increase_Java_Memory_in_Windows

Two of the other reviews in the message that were shown to you during the review ban were review audits, that are slightly different from the one above as they are suggesting external plugins:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22058303
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22114563

In *mostly* link-only answers recommending a tool or library, those links [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605). If users omit to include all of these, it is then treated as a link-only answer and should be deleted.

Comment: How do you get "... especially as it wasn't answering a programming/coding question" from "Seems that increasing the memory available to the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) was the answer"? To me it definitely looks like it could be an applicable solution to a programming problem. As for explaining _why_ a solution resolves an issue, that isn't required. So, whether or not it should be deleted or improved, it unequivocally should **not** have been recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. The review in _this_ case was correct, regardless of their previous reviews.

Comment: @TinyGiant I meant a question that is directly dealing with code

Comment: What's your point? Why was this review referenced in the ban message? I see no reasonable justification for that. Regarding the failed audits, isn't there an automatic ban system that handles that? If so... I don't see any reason for a moderator imposed ban at all, unless there is some other reviews that you haven't addressed here.

Comment: Also, the two audits you reference are in an entirely different queue with an entirely different purpose. Even though they are all short and contain links, they aren't the same at all.

Comment: I guess the Url looked very suspicious, and no one can argue on this one.

Comment: Assuming you banned and today unbaned me - thank you for sharing your point of view. (+1). My best option in that LQ-review probably would have been editing/commenting the post and clarify why I vote 'Looks ok' and that a JVM with too small Heap eats up CPU cycles due to a very busy garbage collector. Maybe the entire question would have been better placed on serverfault.com. All of this showed to me again we learn most from negative feedback.

Comment: @xdtTransform the url doesnt look very suspicious to me, and upon visiting the link it absolutely does not look even remotely like spam. We can definitely argue this one as the OP unequivocally chose the correct decision and they were erroneously banned because of it. Samuel has yet to provide us with any reasonable justification whatsoever for the ban.

Comment: @Selaron no the best option in the LQPRQ for this review is to review as "looks ok", which you did. There is no reason for it to be posted on server fault as it is perfectly on-topic here. You did absolutely nothing wrong and Samuel went out of his way to give you a ban for doing the right thing.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm curious what about `messiahpsychoanalyst.org` **doesn't** look suspicious in a link that's supposed to be about programming. Even when visiting the page it looks suspicious because the site itself isn't mainly about programming. It takes exploring several pages to find out why that site has such a strange setup.

Comment: @Herohtar I guess I just dont assume that everything is spam unless proven otherwise. It doesnt look spammy, regardless of whether the domain name is directly programming related or not. Looking at the content of the link, it looks like a set of steps necessary to increase the memory of a virtual machine as the answer suggests. Assuming that everything is spam unless you already know otherwise seems like a very poor metric.

Comment: @Herohtar based on the domain name, I'd assume it's somebody's blog. We programmers like using nicknames and even incorporating them into our websites. And that looks like a nickname. You should know, you own herohtar.com

Comment: @TinyGiant, I didn't even click the link I google it and "Messiah is one whom the road ends to Him.
He is the road and He is the destination.
He is there, where we begin and He is where we end." . At this point the "This site is being constructed to promote the idea of Messiah is living among us." is not even a big deal anymore. I had to call it spam cause man they know too mutch My Identity has been discorverd

Comment: @xdtTransform what?

Comment: @TinyGiant, random pick from the non-spamy web site. Thats what trigger my first comment. If I were mod and search for a domain and got those result I would hit the red button twice.

Comment: @xdtTransformset but why? It's a domain name. Spam is content which exists solely to promote a product or service, which this does not, soooooo..... I'm not seeing the reasoning for calling it spam.

Comment: @TinyGiant When I visited the page my impression was that they had just copied a portion of wikihow and were linking to it in order to get traffic on the rest of the site (which is completely unrelated to programming). I had to dig around before I could find out that was not the case.

Comment: @Herohtar it sounds like you're trying very hard to make it seem spammy when it clearly isn't

Comment: @TinyGiant No, just trying to say that I understand how someone could have easily thought the link was spam unless they went out of their way to research the site. I'm not claiming that it **is** spammy, but that it is *not* "clearly" non-spammy to everyone.

Comment: @Herohtar so you're saying that you can see how people who aren't paying attention, and who automatically think everything is spam regardless of whether it exists solely to promote a product or service or not, might see this as spam? I still dont understand why that should mean that the one person involved that was paying attention should be punished while everyone else gets to go about willy nilly not paying attention.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm saying that just "paying attention" isn't enough to know that link is legit, and being suspicious of odd URLs is good practice. The fact that the OP was punished for a correct review is more an issue with how the reviewing system works.

Comment: @Herohtar Being overly suspicious of everything you see is _not_ a good practice. There's nothing suspicious about the URL or the content of the URL, which means that if you're seeing anything suspicious there it is because you _want_ to see something suspicious even if there is nothing to see. The review ban was imposed manually by a moderator for this specific review stating that they were in the wrong when they were very clearly in the right. This isn't a problem with the review system but rather the moderator handing out review bans for no reason.

Comment: @TinyGiant On the internet, yes it is. It may not look suspicious to you, but clearly others do not agree; that doesn't mean they just "want" it to be suspicious any more than you just "want" it to not be. I missed the comment that it was a manual ban; in that case, the moderator should have investigated the link in more detail before deciding the review was wrong and worthy of a ban.

Comment: @Herohtar herohtar.com looks just as suspicious as the provided domain name. We dont need to default to the assumption that everything is spam otherwise we will see everything as spam regardless of whether or not it exists solely to promote a product or service. It's not spam unless proven otherwise. What you're saying is it is a link so it should be considered spam unless an in-depth investigation shows otherwise, which is just wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind that the other reviewers reviewed it as "recommend deletion" based on the fact that they didnt think it qualified as an answer. Samuel here is the one who says that the reason for the ban was because the answer is spam when it clearly is not.

Comment: @TinyGiant Not true. Some domains wouldn't look suspicious; for example, a link to [an *actual* wikihow article](https://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7), because it's a commonly known how-to site, whereas a random domain could be anything. Note that I don't disagree that the ban decision was a bad one; what I disagree with is that the legitmacy of the link was unquestionable. The moderation ruling should have happened after verifying whether the assumption was accurate, however.

Comment: @Herohtar I'm not saying that it is unquestionable, I'm saying that there is no evidence to suggest that it is clearly spam as this answer suggests. It is clear upon investigation that it is not spam, and at a glance it does not appear to be spam. Regardless of any reservations, there is no reason for this to be used as reasoning for a manually imposed ban. The fact that someone might think at a glance that it _could_ possibly be spam is completely irrelevant. Also, that wikihow article is flooded with ads, I'd be more inclined to call that spam.

Answer (score 3):

While a bit afraid about plenty of downvotes or comments like 'Looks OK?! lol..' I am happy about your very quick and positive reactions.

Figured out [the answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851742/apache-tomcat-9-on-windows-10?answertab=oldest#tab-top) should not have been deleted and therefore was undeleted by a moderator.

<del>*Will mark this answered in order for noone to spend additional time on it. Edit: will have to wait two days...*</del>

Comment: No need to be too eager in accepting an answer. We were trying to give you some quick feedback, but it’s entirely likely that the moderator who imposed this ban will see this question and explain his reasoning. Maybe he saw a longer history of troubling reviews, and can give some targeted advice on how you can improve your reviewing.