# Why review-banned for a single accidental mouse click?

Tags: support, review-suspension, late-answers

Today while reviewing I accidentally clicked on "No action needed" for a post that should've been flagged as "Not an answer". I recognized my mistake and instantly corrected it: opened my review history, navigated to that post and flagged it as "Not an answer".
Short time later this flag status changed to **helpful**. As a result of this overall **helpful** action I now must read this on stackoverflow.com/review:

> You recently indicated "no action needed" on [this blatant non-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22418945).
>   You should have flagged it as "not an answer" so it could be removed.
>   Please take time to read [our review guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505). Come back on Apr 8 at
>   20:07 to continue reviewing.

Looks to me like a mod did a mistake.

Comment: It would be well out of the ordinary for a mod to *unilaterally* suspend you from review for a ***single*** failed audit...

Comment: Didn't you get any warning messages about _failed audits_ before? Such bans usually don't come out of the blue.

Comment: I had been rightfully review-suspended 8d for bad decisions on `low quality`queue. Have successfully used the time to make it better in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your ban has been lifted.

I imposed it manually for precisely the reasons indicated in the message. It was a fairly long ban (30 days) because you've recently been banned twice by moderators (someone other than me) for making incorrect reviews. Your most recent ban (before this one) was March 1st, and it was for 8 days. Standard practice is to escalate the duration of back-to-back bans.

I missed the fact that you *also* raised a "not an answer" flag on that answer after indicating "no action needed" in the review queue. That is a valid way of correcting your mistake, so I've now corrected mine.

For more details on these types of bans, see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380508/is-there-an-appeal-process-for-review-queue-access-suspension/380522#380522).

Although this particular case was a mistake on both our parts (you made a mis-click and then fixed it; I failed to notice that you had corrected your mistake), I very much disagree that the ban here would have been an overreaction if you had genuinely marked that answer as "no action needed", especially combined with a history of problematic or incorrect reviews.

Comment: Thank you - you are right. My first ban was liftet too because it [turned out to be 'invalid'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379836/why-was-this-answer-by-op-declared-link-only-answer-and-deleted). The second suspension was reasonable. So with that second reasonable suspension that ended today, do I now have to fear a 30d ban on the very next mistake, audit-fail or disputed decision?

Comment: Yes...probably. Your review ban history is tracked in your profile for moderators, and unless we are *really* careful, it's entirely possible that we'll assume these past bans were legitimate and apply a compounding effect on your next blatantly incorrect review. I recommend treading very lightly and being extra-conscientious when reviewing, at least for the next month. Definitely don't fail any audits. @Selaron

Comment: Note that if a user chooses to upvote instead of clicking "No Action Needed", the review will show as "Reviewed", the same as if they opted to flag, downvote, etc. How are those caught?

Comment: @gparyani: That sounds like a subject for another question (and a good one).

Comment: @gparyani They're caught by me paying closer attention. :-) When it says "Reviewed" as the review queue action, I have to check more different places to see what actually happened. That's actually how I missed this one. I saw "No Action Needed", and skipped checking in those other places because I knew "No Action Needed" was the wrong choice. I thought I could save myself some effort. I would personally *love* for the review queue actions to be more detailed in the steps that were actually taken, even if moderator-only.

Comment: In my 1st edition of the Q I worte "overreaction" because I considered my first mistakes having been punished by that 8d-suspension and should not be punished again. I knew about automatic suspensions by audit failure grow in length exponentially but thought this would be different from modded suspensions. Will the next one be like 3 or 6month disregarding this one was liftet?

Comment: @Selaron Moderator-imposed suspensions for review also grow exponentially, but it's based on moderator judgment. We have to manually select a time. It's not going to be 3-6 months. I'm just saying, it's possible that if you make another misclick, a moderator could impose a 30 day ban or so, without a full appreciation of your history. If that does happen, ping me and I'll look into it. But please just try and make sure it *doesn't* happen by paying close attention when reviewing. If you don't fail any audits, and don't vote "no action needed" on any obvious non-answers, you should be fine.

Comment: off topic and likely subject for another Q, I think there's urgent need for automatic notice on overruled (not helpful) review descisions. This already exists for `flags` - when previous flags where disputed, you get a notice with advice to review those flags before going on with next flagging. This would help increase review quality for new reviewers or those ones so far not worse enought to get suspended. "At least one of your previous review descision was overruled. Pleas take a closer look on review X and Y and confirm you did. Afterwards, you can go on reviewing".

Comment: Yes, review queues need a lot of work. I agree. It doesn't seem to be a priority for the developers at the moment. Feel free to post [[meta-tag:feature-request]]s if you have concrete, actionable suggestions. The only problem with that is, [who decides what was the correct decision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380967/#comment675766_380967)? Different from flags, which are handled by moderators, reviews are done by the community and the final decision may actually be wrong. So it's risky to add warnings, and the implementation of this will take some more thought. @sel